# Can I share Google Cloud Messaging API key?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, api-key

I'm planning to use Google Cloud Messaging in order to let users be notified when their own server has an alert to send.

In this perspective, they will have to install a small script that will be called by a service on their server: it will use Google Cloud Messaging to send a message that will finally be displayed on their Android device:

```
Server(script) -> Google Cloud Messaging -> Device
```

The downside is that my Google Cloud Messaging API key will be shared with my users since it will be unencrypted in the script on their server.

Documentation states that

> Note: Note the API key displayed when you configure your project, **and store it securely** on your app server. You'll need it to send downstream messages to the client app.

---

So here's my question: should I share this API key publicly or should I use an intermediate script:

```
Server(script) -> "proxy" -> Google Cloud Messaging -> Device
```

Is there any way spammers could use this API key to send unwanted notifications to my users?

Comment: 2 things here. They need to have both APIkey and GCM regId to send message. Also They need right action tag to preform some action on phone side.

Comment: Since both sender (server-side script) and receiver (Android app) apps are open-source, they would easily be able to get the action tags. But the GCM regId is indeed necessary to "spam" devices. Thanks

Comment: I think it's advisable to avoid exposing this API key either way. Even if spammers don't have the registration ID, they could keep spamming the GCM server using your own API key in a trial-and-error way. You might want to run through [this document](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#apikeybestpractices).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't found this document when doing my first lookout. Could you write an answer so I can accept it?